# How to iterate so that the dict has different Name,Height,Weight,Bmi in Python?

Tags: python-3.x

```
metric units or imperial units: metric
Enter name: a
Height in meters: 1.5
Weight in kg: 50
a's BMI is: 22.22222222222222, you are normal.
Enter name: a
Height in meters: 1.7
Weight in kg: 100
a's BMI is: 34.602076124567475, you are overweight.
{'Name': 'a', 'Height': 1.7, 'Weight': 100, 'Bmi': 34.602076124567475}
{'Name': 'a', 'Height': 1.7, 'Weight': 100, 'Bmi': 34.602076124567475}
```

Comment: not sure exactly what you're asking - do you want to iterate over a dict containing this information? do you want to convert metric to imperial units?

Comment: I have already converted metric to imperial, when you look at my question there are two dict's containing the same values when the input i have given is different. So, i want to iterate in such a way where each dict has different values...not sure how to do that?

Comment: can you include the code where you define these two dicts?

Comment: BMI={}
units = input('metric units or imperial units: ')
if units =='metric':
    for i in range(1,3):
     name = input('Enter name: ')
     BMI['Name'] = name
     height=float(input('Height in meters: '))
     BMI['Height']=height
     weight = int(input('Weight in kg: '))
     BMI['Weight']=weight
     bmi= weight/(height*height)
     BMI['Bmi']=bmi

Comment: if bmi <18.5:
         print('{}\'s BMI is: {}, you are underweight.'.format(name,bmi) )
     elif bmi > 18.5 and bmi <25:
         print('{}\'s BMI is: {}, you are normal.'.format(name, bmi))
     elif bmi > 25:
         print('{}\'s BMI is: {}, you are overweight.'.format(name, bmi))
elif units =='imperial':
    name = input('Enter name: ')
    BMI['Name'] = name
    height=float(input('Height in inches: '))
    BMI['Height']=height
    weight = int(input('Weight in lb: '))
    BMI['Weight']=weight
    bmi= weight*703/(height*height)
    BMI['Bmi']=bmi

Comment: if bmi < 18.5:
        print('{}\'s BMI is: {}, you are underweight.'.format(name, bmi))
    elif bmi > 18.5 and bmi < 25:
        print('{}\'s BMI is: {}, you are normal.'.format(name, bmi))
    elif bmi > 25:
        print('{}\'s BMI is: {}, you are overweight.'.format(name, bmi))
for i in range(1,3):
    print(BMI)

Comment: user11072857. Please format the code. We cant help you because we cant read it

Comment: How do i format my code?

Comment: @user11072857 include this part of the code in the formatted part of your original question - inside the triple quotes (``` ```)